# Check if value in a cell is 'yes' within a group

Tags: excel, vba

example:
I would like to know with vba if everyone in a year paid. So did everyone in year 1, year 2 etc pay?

| payed | student | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | smith | 1 |
| yes | jackson | 1 |
| no | ferral | 2 |
| no | hamilton | 3 |
| yes | jenner | 1 |
| no | west | 2 |
| yes | sullivan | 2 |

result:

| payed | student | year | year-completely-paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | smith | 1 | yes |
| yes | jackson | 1 | yes |
| no | ferral | 2 | no |
| no | hamilton | 3 | no |
| yes | jenner | 1 | yes |
| no | west | 2 | no |
| yes | sullivan | 2 | no |

All students in year 1 have 'yes' in `year-completely-paid` because all these students payed.

Comment: Does it need to be VBA? A formula will work for this.

Comment: @Warcupine yes. But you made me curious about the formula. What is it?

Comment: Try with countifs(), be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA solution using a dictionary to get any no for the year.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim currentyear As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        
        For i = 2 To lr
            currentyear = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            If dict.exists(currentyear) Then
                If dict(currentyear) = "yes" And .Cells(i, 1).Value = "no" Then
                    dict(currentyear) = "no"
                End If
            Else
                dict.Add currentyear, .Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        
        For i = 2 To lr
            currentyear = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = dict(currentyear)
        Next i
    End With
```

Formula solution:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C$2:C$8,C3,A$2:A$8,"no") > 0,"no","yes")
```

Change the ending row as needed.